# What is the difference between SystemVerilog If and implication operator (->) in constraint block?

Tags: system-verilog

SystemVerilog contains something called a constraint block which is used in pseudorandom stimulus generation. It also contains a conditional called 'if' as it does in all programming languages. But, there is one more thing which is the implication operator. This is written as `->`

With regards to the `constraint` block, what is the difference between the implication operator `->` and the `if` statement? How do we know which one to use?

Also, why are we able to use `==` on both left hand side and right hand side of the `->` ? I am unable to make sense of why `->` exists and so there are a few files written for UVM testbench that make no sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

The IEEE Std 1800-2017 states in section 18.5.7 *if–else constraints*:

> The **if–else** style constraint declarations are equivalent to
> implications

Which one you choose is a matter of coding style.

There are often many ways to accomplish equivalent behavior in Verilog.  For example, combinational logic can be described with continuous assignments, procedural assignments in `always` blocks or with built-in gate primitives.

> why do we need to use == on both left hand side and right hand side of
> the -> ?

In general, that is not always the case.  This is legal:

```
rand bit a;
rand bit [1:0] b;
constraint c1 { a -> b==3; }
```

Comment: I have updated my question. So now it asks, why are we able to use == on both the LHS and the RHS as well? From what I understand, what we are telling the tool is, if LHS is true then RHS should also be true and if its not, generate new random numbers and do this untilm this condition becomes true.

Answer (score 0):

Constraints are sets of equations that the solver tries to find random values that make these equations evaluate true. They are not procedural statements.

The implication operator `A -> B` is a shortcut for the equation `!A || B` where A and B can be any boolean equations (Actually B can be another set of constraints)

Somebody had the bright idea to use the `if/else` keywords in a constraint. But they still form boolean equations and are not procedural statements.

```
 if (A) B; else C;
```

is the boolean equation

```
(!A || B) && (A || C)
```